# System.Data.Operators' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

Tags: vb.net

Help please to fix that.
For the first 4 is error "'System.Data.Operators' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'."

```
    bool1 = (Operators.CompareString = Me.url) "http://HIDDENLINK/WiHome", False) = 0)

    bool1 = (Operators.CompareString(Me.url, "https://HIDDENLINK/ProfilesGate?nextpage=http%3A%2F%2FHIDDENLINK%2FDefault", False) = 0)

    bool1 = (Operators.CompareString(Me.url, "https://HIDDENLINK.com/ProfilesGate?nextpage=http://HIDDENLINK/Default", False) = 0)

bool1 = (Operators.CompareString(Me.url, "https://HIDDENLINK/home?locale=en-US", False) = 0)
```

Comment: try `String.Compare( strA, strB)` instead

Comment: For that code: http://prntscr.com/5wjk4k
I get error that: http://prntscr.com/5wjkgu
If I change that to that String

Comment: well, if you absolutely must have a bool return, use `String.Equals(objA.ToString, objB.ToString)`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5wjoud End of Statement there :/

Comment: not enough showing in that snippet.  Intellisense should help you know what to put where and what is expected.  The code I posted is complete - no extra or empty slots as with your `, , `.

Comment: Removed both , , nothing happened. http://prntscr.com/5wjt52

Comment: Also, where is problem here? http://prntscr.com/5wjtzm If I open TXT file it should show text in ListBox1, but program just gonna close

Comment: we dont do "also" here.  one question per post. that snippiet does not use  String.Compare or String.Equals

Comment: @Plutonix If I click on that button I choose my txt file and it should put all text in to ListBox, but program closes and shows that: http://prntscr.com/5wjxak
Please help me :), you are very helpful

Comment: `Imports Operators = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators`

Comment: Thanks, I need someone who got Skype or somewhere I can chat. I really need someone help me with my code, because im not that expirenced :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are writing to the same boolean variable 4 times in a row but you can do this one of two ways. The `False` part at the end allows you to specify whether or not the strings should be compared case specific or not. As you had in your example the `False` part specifies that the strings must equal each other perfectly with the same lowercase and uppercase characters:

```
bool1 = String.Compare(Me.url, "http://HIDDENLINK/WiHome", False) = 0

bool1 = String.Compare(Me.url, "https://HIDDENLINK/ProfilesGate?nextpage=http%3A%2F%2FHIDDENLINK%2FDefault", False) = 0

bool1 = String.Compare(Me.url, "https://HIDDENLINK.com/ProfilesGate?nextpage=http://HIDDENLINK/Default", False) = 0

bool1 = String.Compare(Me.url, "https://HIDDENLINK/home?locale=en-US", False) = 0
```

Or if you know you want to compare strings that match the case exactly this is another way to do the same:

```
bool1 = Me.url = "http://HIDDENLINK/WiHome"

bool1 = Me.url = "https://HIDDENLINK/ProfilesGate?nextpage=http%3A%2F%2FHIDDENLINK%2FDefault"

bool1 = Me.url = "https://HIDDENLINK.com/ProfilesGate?nextpage=http://HIDDENLINK/Default"

bool1 = Me.url = "https://HIDDENLINK/home?locale=en-US"
```

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå my comment about not worrying about case sensitivity was meant to convey that you don't have to worry about flipping a variable to make it case specific or not. I can see how this could be read to mean that it's actually a case insensitive comparison so I updated my explanations of the code pieces to hopefully make things more clear. Thanks for pointing that out!